# Share Sqlite with iTune file sharing within iOS App.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I know that we can share file  from app to computer (iTunes), i want to know that can i share Sqlite file with iTunes or there is any way to import sqlite file to excel and then share this excel file from app to iTunes. Any code or help will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: you want to see database after use

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is application feature. Will use this data for further activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this key in .plist  and solve your problem

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

`Specifies whether the application shares files with the user’s computer through iTunes`. By [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Comment: Will it allow me for sharing Sqlite file ? and What about images which are store in sqlite with blob data type?

Comment: Let me check, ill back to you once i have test Thanks